# Deleting/Closing a user does not work

Tags: docusignapi

I'm making a call to:
DELETE {baseurl}/accounts/{accountId}/users

Request body contains:

```
{"users":[{"email":"<an email>"}]}
```

Response:
ERROR 400 Bad Request

```
{"errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_BODY",
"message": "The request body is missing or improperly formatted."}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the documentation for the correct parameter usage: https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Close%20a%20User.htm?Highlight=delete%20user

FYI I tested and a DELETE worked fine. I used the following JSON.

```
{
  "users":[{
    "userId":"7f7d3f01-9894-4479-9108-fee8c250xxxx"
  }]
}
```

Comment: I tried the following request:

    {"users":[{"userId":"<user ID>"}]}

But still getting the same result as before.

Comment: Can you copy/paste a sample userID you are using (you can mask part of it)? it needs to be an actual ID and not an email@.

Comment: 7929ea0f-b2e7-47e4-956f-***

I don't use the email in the body.

Comment: Per the error you are receiving, I think you are getting burned by copy/paste. Please sanity check that there are no extraneous characters in your call. You can also enable API logging on your DEMO account so you can see exactly what your request/response looks like from a DocuSign perspective.

Comment: I'm using the DocuSign api explorer (new version). here is the sample request body I see:
{"users":[{"userId":"7929ea0f-b2e7-47e4-956f-3f9bf56410e1"}]}

Comment: Agreed, i am seeing the same behavior via the API explorer. Looks like a small but w/the explorer there.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to "delete" the user using RestSharp. So it is an api explorer issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this in the API explorer. Please try now and let me know in case you are still running into issues.